# Link Header not showing in console

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, pagination, axios

I am building a Django and Vue.js application. In my Django Settings
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'drf_link_header_pagination.LinkHeaderPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 10
I have a problem with pagination.
in console>Network Tab. Link showing.

```
...
Link: <http://127.0.0.1:8000/phones/?page=2>; rel="next", <http://127.0.0.1:8000/phones/?page=10>; rel="last"
...
```

But when I tried to access it in my Vue component.

```
axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/phones/`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.phones = res.data
          console.log(res.headers.link)
        })
```

But it doesn't exist there. It returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself :)
I added expose header to Django settings and it is ok

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['link']
```